# Offer the user to add password for local account after login in with social login - Azure AD b2c

Tags: openid-connect, azure-ad-b2c

I have a web application that uses Azure b2c to authenticate users. I would like the following user experience:

1. The user tries to access a page behind login
2. The user is redirected to azure b2c and can choose to login with facebook or email+password
3. If the user is a new user, they will only be able to log in with facebook
4. After login with facebook the user should be offered to also create a password that they can use in the future instead of facebook
5. If the user declines to create a password, we need to remember this (in a cookie?) and not offer the user this option again in the future
6. Somehow we need to be able to trigger the option of creating a password again at a later point in time, if the user changes her mind

What is the best way to implement this kind of flow? Can it be built in azure b2c with custom policies? Or is it too complex?

Comment: Does the user logging in with facebook idp have a local account already created.?

Comment: no. I expect the local account to be created after facebook login if it does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

**GOALS**

I suspect this is what you're aiming for:

- Put the user in control, so that login usability is good, and familiar credentials can be used
- Identify the user via a Stable User Id in your back end, whichever login method they use, so that you can track their data over time

A good question is why do you need the user to have a default password?

**POST LOGIN BEHAVIOUR**

I would maybe prompt the user to 'complete their profile' after login in order to enable the above. This behaviour is nothing to do with OAuth and belongs in your app:

- Prompt for an email if you don't have one already
- Create a Users row in your own database if the email doesn't exist already

**FEDERATED LOGINS**

Azure AD has features where you can enable this. So login via Facebook should be fine.

**USER SELF SIGN UP**

Azure AD will support this also (I think). So the user could follow prompts to create their own account - if that makes sense in terms of your business.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. To answer your question "Why do you need the user to have a password": 
The facebook login is used as an example. In reality it might be another type of login that also supports OpenId connect. And this login might be more secure but also more troublesome for the user. So the idea is that the password might be faster. Furthermore there might be a cost associated with the OpenId Connect provider. So we would like the users to use mail + passwords instead to avoid a redirect to the OpenId Connect provider. But the first login needs to use the provider.

Comment: In terms of what is technically possible I would say the first login could be either. You won't be able to get Azure AD to authenticate the user in 2 different ways. One option that would work is to prompt the user to create a password upon return to your app. Then use Azure user management APIs to create the user in Azure AD. That is not recommended though, because with OAuth, the app should never see the user's password

Comment: @Nikolaj Looking for solution where the external IDP will be treated as SignUp/SignIn and B2C IDP will only be treated as SignIn. 
**Approach** User try to use the email and password he/she get error of non-existing account. User try to use External IDP and login, it will redirected to  B2C and check if **useridentity** attribute present or not by reading alternateSecurityID in Policy, if not a step where user will asked to provide password and then account will be created in B2C and also emailAddress will be added to signInName attribute which will help later in login with Email+Password.

Answer (score 0):

The Azure AD B2C Custom custom policy sample, https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/sign-up-with-social-and-local-account, demonstrate how to sign a Facebook account with a local password.

The [**SelfAsserted-Social**](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/blob/0812acd217955083b6e04599ce48918f8022d4da/policies/sign-up-with-social-and-local-account/TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml#L65) technical profile prompts for an e-mail address (which must be verified) and a new password.

The [**AAD-UserWriteUsingAlternativeSecurityId**](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/blob/0812acd217955083b6e04599ce48918f8022d4da/policies/sign-up-with-social-and-local-account/TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml#L92) technical profile then creates a user account in the Azure AD B2C directory with both a password credential and the Facebook identity.